# How to fix Python issues in Command Prompt Console?

Tags: python, cmd

While trying to enter any commands with Python the only result which I receive is output: Python
[image: Picture of issue]

Comment: `python3 -m pip install freegames`, or just `pip install freegames`

Comment: While using the first command the output you already saw, but when I use the second command it writes, that: "Requirement already satisfied", but the problem is that It still doesn't recognise freegames